# Does Linux top command affect performance in of itself?

Tags: performance-testing

I want to have a script continuously monitor (in intervals of 1 second) total & process-specific CPU & RAM usage while I have a separate program running. However, I worry that my results would be skewed because perhaps the simple act of asking the OS to give me this information may itself affect CPU & RAM usage. Does anyone know if running a command, such as "top" in Linux has a significant performance impact?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top uses very little resources, but if you are worried about it altering your monitoring, consider that top command also monitors itself. For instance, in my notebook:

```
top - 10:50:23 up  1:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.36, 0.59, 0.60
Tasks: 321 total,   1 running, 320 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.4 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.0 id,  0.2 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7865.9 total,    621.3 free,   3652.5 used,   3592.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  24000.0 total,  24000.0 free,      0.0 used.   3049.8 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2882 lrojas    20   0 1264648 207704  73156 S   7.9   2.6   8:00.64 mattermost-desk
 2886 lrojas    20   0 1255748 188332  68476 S   7.0   2.3   6:29.08 mattermost-desk
 1850 lrojas    20   0  477724 145512 117548 S   4.3   1.8   2:15.58 Xorg
 2564 lrojas    20   0  634468  39260  27884 S   4.3   0.5   0:09.65 gnome-terminal-
 1959 lrojas    20   0 3717332 266448 179640 S   3.0   3.3   2:33.57 gnome-shell
 2186 lrojas    20   0 1651424 162284  78792 S   1.7   2.0   2:11.41 mattermost-desk
 2651 lrojas    20   0 2850312 492984 179248 S   1.7   6.1   5:56.44 firefox
 3542 lrojas    20   0 2289588 483896 123204 S   1.3   6.0   3:31.26 Web Content
 3120 lrojas    20   0 1605924 121008  76764 S   0.7   1.5   0:16.89 WebExtensions
 4090 lrojas    20   0 2034256 422128 114792 S   0.7   5.2   1:04.14 Web Content
 7358 lrojas    20   0 1701508 213840 126108 S   0.7   2.7   0:24.12 Web Content
 7564 lrojas    20   0  228920   5080   4268 R   0.7   0.1   0:00.07 top
```

On the last line you can see top, using 0.7% CPU and some memory.

So, if that level of resource utilization is important for you, you can discount it from total and update the results of the system accordingly.

For instance, in this case. There is 95.0% idle, out of 100%, but 0.7% was used by top.

95.0 / (1 - 0.7%) = 95.0% / 0.993 = 95.67% idle, if top had not been running.